# How to get list of subfolders in a hdfs folder?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Suppose I have my parquets stored as follows:

```
hdfs://root/folder1/pqt1.pqt
hdfs://root/folder2/pqt2.pqt
hdfs://root/folder3/pqt3.pqt
hdfs://root/folder4/part1/pqt4part1.pqt
hdfs://root/folder4/part2/pqt4part1.pqt
...
```

How do I list the subfolders in 'hdfs://root' in R using `sparklyr`? The desired output would be (without recursion):

```
hdfs://root/folder1/
hdfs://root/folder2/
hdfs://root/folder3/
hdfs://root/folder4/
...
```

and with recursion:

```
hdfs://root/folder1/
hdfs://root/folder2/
hdfs://root/folder3/
hdfs://root/folder4/
hdfs://root/folder4/part1/
hdfs://root/folder4/part2/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

base R is probably enough

`list.dirs(path = "hdfs://root", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am connecting to a remote spark cluster. Will this still work?

Comment: @Alex only one way to find out ;-)